# Form validation of multiple values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to consolidate all the validation values in one function by calling out one php file. It manage to validate but somehow if I validate one field, another field message will also come out.

Form:

```
<input name="SNo" type="text" id="SNo" onkeyup="Validate(this.value)" value=""/> <span id="validateNumbers"></span>
<input name="Names" type="text" id="Names" onkeyup="Validate(this.value)" value=""/><span id="validateNames"></span>
```

Javascript function:

```
function Validate(value) {
    var SNo = document.getElementById('SNo').value;
    var Names = document.getElementById('Names').value;
    if (str == SNo) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("validateNumbers").innerHTML = "Must not be blank";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("validateNumbers").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "functions/validate.php?SNo=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} else if (str == Names) {
    //same coding as if statement
} else {}
}
```

So if i leave it blank, both validateNumbers and validateNames errors message will appear as well as other messages. I did not use any looping but why it will repeat.. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str is not defined. Better to pass in input object itself.

```
function Validate(field) {
    var SNo = document.getElementById('SNo');
    var Names = document.getElementById('Names');

    if (field == SNo) {
        if (field.value.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("validateNumbers").innerHTML = "Must not be blank";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("validateNumbers").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "functions/validate.php?SNo=" + field.value, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    } else if (field == Names) {
        //same coding as if statement
    } else {}
}
```

and

```
<input name="SNo" type="text" id="SNo" onkeyup="Validate(this)" value=""/>
<input name="Names" type="text" id="Names" onkeyup="Validate(this)" value=""/>
```

Comment: hi, it's defined at the input onkeyup= validate(this.value)

Comment: Yes, but you never use the variable 'value' in your Validate function

Comment: I did. It can validate. It's just that the messages for validateNumbers and ValidateNames appear at the same time...

Comment: thanks but both error message still shows out. By right should be if i type in wrong number in SNo field only validateNumbers message will come out but now is both...